# How to add char to calculated field in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I want to put in the field the following expression: `=Year(Fields!TaskOpenDate.Value) +  "-" +  Month(Fields!TaskOpenDate.Value)` that I want is to show in the field like this: 02-2014.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Since it seems like *TaskOpenDate* is already a `DateTime`, you can just `Format` this the way you want:

```
=Format(Fields!TaskOpenDate.Value, "MM-yyyy")
```

Comment: This answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You're close but Year() and Month() return data as Integers. You're then using the + operator on the Integers returned by Year() and Month() to try and concatenate those with a string, which is confusing it.

Just convert the return from Year() and Month() to string as well, and it'll be fine:

```
=CStr(Month(Fields!TaskOpenDate.Value)) + "-" + CStr(Year(Fields!TaskOpenDate.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give your required date format

```
=   Right("0"+CStr(Month(Fields!TaskOpenDate.Value)),2) +"-"+ 
    CStr(Year(Fields!TaskOpenDate.Value))
```